# How do I made a relation in two entities if one entity has arrays data

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sequelize.js

I have two tables name `users` and `requests` in MYSQL database here is json example of each sequelize model which I need to map to my models:

user:

```
{
   "username": "",
   "profileImage": "",
   "deleted": false,
   "active": false,
   "id": 9,
   "uuid": "9a6d5a15-8e11-42aa-ac56-0bec272c9287",
   "firstName": "M",
   "lastName": "Aslam",
   "email": "hang@outlook.com",
   "isGuest": false
}
```

and `request`

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "requestUUID": "ab966593-95e5-4fd8-b433-01b116e3edee",
  "socialLinks": [
    {
      "url": "https://synavos.com",
      "socialLinks": [
        {
          "platform": "facebook",
          "handle": "https://www.facebook.com/synavos/"
        },
        {
          "platform": "instagram",
          "handle": "https://www.instagram.com/synavosbusiness/"
        },
        {
          "platform": "youtube",
          "handle": "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrZxxAV_OiRb9N3wIe3N94w"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "url": "https://www.confiz.com/",
      "socialLinks": [
        {
          "platform": "facebook",
          "handle": "http://www.facebook.com/ConfizCareers"
        },
        {
          "platform": "youtube",
          "handle": "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCG64lwoDIbwtkZK8E_s140A"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

while a user can have many requests while a request belongs to one user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the relation is one to mant (*user can have many requests while a request belongs to one user*) you can add to `request` a `user_id` field. then you can search all request of the user by `SELECT * FROM requests where user_id = ?`, `[user.id]`, and if you want find the user of a specific request use `SELECT ALL FROM users WHERE id = ?`, `[request.user_id]`

Comment: How do I handle `socialLinks` arrays in requests table?

Comment: Any array means you need one more table for it. You should have one more table for `socials` with columns `id`, `url`, `request_id`. And one more table for `links` with columns `id`, `social_id`, `platform`, `handle`

Comment: Then `SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN requests on users.id = requests.user_id LEFT JOIN socials ON request.id = social.request_id LEFT JOIN links ON social.id = links.social_id`

Comment: and if you want it in object structure you should iterate through users and fetch for each the request. the iterate the request and fetch for each the socials, and for each socials the links